# Designing a many-body physics course

Tags: quantum-field-theory, education, many-body

Preface: This might be an unusual question for this forum.

Owing to the lack of a course on many-body physics offered in my department, I am planning to organize a many-body physics study group. Since I have dabbled with QFT and some many-body physics in the past, I am designing the syllabus. My understanding of the subject is patchy, and I need help figuring out the big picture.

My first confusion is about the perturbative expansion, done after studying second quantization. There seem to be two ways of doing it:

1. Derive the Gell-Mann Low theorem in the interaction picture, then use Wick's theorem and introduce Feynman diagrams. Now somehow derive Dyson's equation. [Fetter & Walecka, Mahan]
2. Find the single-particle Green's function by inverting the hamiltonian, getting Dyson's equation along the way. Then introduce Feynman diagrams from the expansion of Dyson's equation. This approach also uses "lesser/greater" Green's functions. [Bruus & Flensberg]

The second confusion is regarding the functional integral approach. Are there advantages to sticking with standard diagrammatic perturbation theory for solving example problems, before introducing path integrals, or is it a more modern (and better) approach to start with path integrals (introducing mean-field as a saddle point approximation).